How to load existing HttpIntegration from APIGatewayv2 using AWS CDK
I'm wondering if there might be a way to load an existing HttpIntegration within the APIGatewayv2 CDK library.  I tried looking in a few places as outlined below but very possible that I missed something obvious.  Thanks!
Tried looking in the following places:

In the AWS APIGatewayv2 CDK library, there is a way to load an existing HttpAuthorizer using the "fromHttpAuthorizerAttributes" method.  However, there does not seem to be a similar method available for the HttpIntegration construct.
Looking through the methods available in the underlying "CfnIntegration" construct, there did not seem to be any that would enable loading an existing integration.
Looked in the "HttpLambdaIntegration" Class but also did not find any method or initializer parameter that would allow an existing integration to be referenced.

